# VBA display comment with original formatting

Tags: excel, vba

How can I display the copied comment **FONT** the same as original comment (e.g still wants part of the comment **bold** and underlined)?

[image: comment]

```
Sub Comments()

Dim X As Long, RngName As String, curwks As Worksheet

Sheet1.Select
Set curwks = ActiveSheet

If curwks.Comments.Count Then
Sheet2.Select
Range("A1").Select
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For X = 1 To curwks.Comments.Count
        With curwks.Comments.Item(X)
           Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(X, 0).Resize(1, 1) = _
                Array(.Text)
        End With
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I think you'll have to loop through each character and ascertain its attributes.

Comment: Hi SJR, thank you very much for your reply, is it possible to give an example?

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: Hi SJR, I am still struggling with it and help would be much appreciated. Regards Jean

Comment: I will try to look at this today.

Comment: I am actually looking at this now. So you are trying to transfer the comments to cells with the formatting, not copying the comment from cell to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a full solution because the `Underline` portion doesn't work for some reason, possibly a bug. If I get a chance I'll look into it, but something might be better than nothing.

```
Sub Comments()

Dim X As Long, i As Long

If Sheet1.Comments.Count Then
    For X = 1 To Sheet1.Comments.Count
        With Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(X, 0)
            .Clear
            .Font.Bold = False
            .Font.Underline = False
            .Value = Sheet1.Comments.Item(X).Text
        End With
        With Sheet1.Comments.Item(X).Shape.TextFrame
            For i = 1 To .Characters.Count
                If .Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True Then
                    Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(X, 0).Characters(i, 1).Font.Bold = True
                End If
                If .Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = True Then
                    Sheet2.Range("A1").Offset(X, 0).Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = True
                End If
            Next i
        End With
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi SJR, Wow, it's working!!! Thank you very much, you don't know what a relief this is. Bold was my main concern, I don't have to use the underlining. Thanks again.